# issue when redirect to livewire component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i installed livewire successfully but when i return the page and the page has
this

```
@livewire('counter')
```

it returns error
Livewire\Redirector::component(): Argument #1 ($component) must be of type Livewire\Component, App\Http\Livewire\Counter given

here is my test page

```
    @extends('layouts.master')
@section('css')

@section('title')
    empty
@stop
@endsection
@section('page-header')
<!-- breadcrumb -->
<div class="page-title">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h4 class="mb-0"> </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb pt-0 pr-0 float-left float-sm-right ">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#" class="default-color">Home</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Page Title</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- breadcrumb -->
@endsection
@section('content')
<!-- row -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-30">
        <div class="card card-statistics h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
                @livewire('counter')
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- row closed -->
@endsection
@section('js')

@endsection
```

and my livewire/counter.blade.php page

```
    <div>
    hello world
</div>
```

and route

```
    Route::get('test', function () {
    return view('test');
});
```

Comment: What does the PHP class look like?

Comment: Ensure that your `App\Http\Livewire\Counter` class extends `Livewire\Compoent`